# Application Wide Modal Issue rails 5 Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have setup modals for my new and edit actions in my users controller. To keep display consistency I would like my user show page to appear in a modal as well.

Right now users access their show page via

```
<li><%= link_to "View Profile", current_user %></li>
```

Link in my nav-bar.

I would like to set this link to display the desired modal for the show action in my user controller.

Im stuck, I've tried to google how to do this but I don't think I am asking the right questions. If anyone can direct me to a resource or give me general outline of how to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated!

I realize this question is a bit Vague but i'm not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rails js if you only want to load the profile when clicked.

**1.** Set `remote: true` on the link tag.

```
<li><%= link_to "View Profile", current_user, remote: true %></li>
```

**2.** Create a partial containing the modal so we can render it via rails js.

`app/views/users/_show.html.erb`

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "modal fade", id: dom_id(@user, :modal) do %>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**3.** Append the partial containing the modal and then toggle it using rails js. Rails will look for the corresponding `.js.erb` view when `remote: true` is set.

`app/views/users/show.js.erb`

```
$('body').append('<%= j render "users/show" %>');  // Append modal
$('#<%= dom_id @user, :modal %>').modal('toggle'); // Toggle modal
```

Comment: do i need to add a format block to the show action and add format.js to it?

Comment: Only if you are supporting both .html and .js @ShawnWilson

Comment: Got it going, i added :remote => true instead of remote:true thanks again for the Bailout!

Comment: good work but if you have current user object than why we need to access controller action?

Comment: Well, both `user_path(@user)` and `current_user` will route to the same action. This pattern is applicable throughout the application just by adding `remote: true` to any user link. I was assuming hed would reuse this modal for both. @uzaif

Comment: Also, if my syntax was invalid that most likely means you are on ruby 1.9, I always recommend upgrading if possible. (Personally, I use rbenv and chruby).  @ShawnWilson

Comment: your solution is good but if we need application wide modal than we can put it in application layout. and if user is login we will fill content in modal based on current_user object

Comment: @codyeatworld - No i am running ruby 2.3.1 in this app, i typed out remote too quickly too lol.. missed the o in remote hence the error lol.. everything is working just fine as you suggested! thanks.

Comment: @uzaif - yes thats true, however cody's method is actually much quicker to implement and is not as clunky as it is all neatly packaged under the user views as opposed to sitting at the bottom of the app layout page

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <%= render 'users/show', user: current_user %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But would I just add the user show controller action to application controller? Or dose the render alleviate the need to do so?